# Drf throttling restart when POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created some app and want to set up different throttling for GET/POST,PUT,PATCH. When I make a GET request, it works fine. But when I perfom POST/PUT/PATCH it looks like cache is restarted. I want to create also extra headers so that's why I think this is actually the problem.

**Throttling.py**

```
class SetHeaders:
    def throttle_success(self):
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        print(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        print(f"REMAIN TIME {self.duration - (self.now - self.history[-1])}")
        print(f'LIMIT {self.get_rate()}')
        print(f'REMAIN RATE {self.num_requests - len(self.history) + 1}')
        return True

class UserPostRateThrottle(SetHeaders, throttling.UserRateThrottle):
    scope = "user_post"

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        if request.method == "GET":
            return True
        return super().allow_request(request, view)
        
class UserGetRateThrottle(SetHeaders, throttling.UserRateThrottle):
    scope = "user_get"

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        if request.method in ("POST", "PUT", "PATCH"):
            return True
        return super().allow_request(request, view)
```

**views.py**

```
class TruckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Truck.confirmed.all()
    serializer_class = TruckSerializer
    filterset_class = TruckFilter
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.DjangoModelPermissions,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )
    throttle_classes = (UserGetRateThrottle, UserPostRateThrottle)

    def _get_images(self, request):
        for img in request.data.getlist("image"):
            image_serializer = TruckImageSerializer(data={"image": img})
            image_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data.get("image"):
            self._get_images(request)
        return super(TruckViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data.get("image"):
            self._get_images(request)
        return super(TruckViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TruckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = LocationSerializer(
        read_only=True,
    )
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
    )
    name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        validators=[
            validators.UniqueValidator(queryset=Truck.confirmed.all())
        ],
    )
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    payment_methods = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Truck
        fields = (
            "id",
            "owner",
            "name",
            "phone",
            "email",
            "facebook",
            "instagram",
            "page_url",
            "description",
            "city",
            "payment_methods",
            "images",
            "updated",
            "location",
        )

    def _get_payments(self, data):
        new_payments = []
        payments = data.get("payment_methods")
        for payment in payments.split(", "):
            try:
                filtered_payment = PaymentMethod.objects.get(
                    payment_name__iexact=payment
                ).id
            except PaymentMethod.DoesNotExist:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "Given payment method does not match"
                )
            new_payments.append(filtered_payment)
        return new_payments

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = self.context.get("view").request.data
        new_payments = data.get("payment_methods", {})
        if new_payments:
            new_payments = self._get_payments(data)
        truck = Truck.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if data.get("image"):
            for image_data in data.getlist("image"):
                TruckImage.objects.create(truck=truck, image=image_data)
        truck.payment_methods.add(*new_payments)
        return truck

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        data = self.context.get("view").request.data
        method = self.context.get("view").request.method
        new_payments = data.get("payment_methods", {})
        if new_payments:
            new_payments = self._get_payments(data)
        if data.get("image"):
            images = instance.images.all()
            if images.exists():
                instance.images.all().delete()
            for image_data in data.getlist("image"):
                TruckImage.objects.create(truck=instance, image=image_data)
        if method == "PUT" or method == "PATCH" and new_payments:
            instance.payment_methods.clear()
        instance.payment_methods.add(*new_payments)
        return super(TruckSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    def get_images(self, obj):
        images = obj.images.all()
        return [img.image.url for img in images]

    def get_payment_methods(self, obj):
        return obj.payment_methods.values_list("payment_name", flat=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES": [
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
        # 'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES": {
        "user_get": "6/day",
        "user_post": "4/day",
        # 'user': '5/day'
    },
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 10,
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": [
        "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS": "rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning",
}
```

So when GET requested is performed I get:

```
>>>REMAIN TIME 86399.02145123482
>>>LIMIT 6/day
>>>REMAIN RATE 3
and so on...
```

But in case of other request i get the same info all the time

```
>>>REMAIN TIME 86400.0
>>>LIMIT 4/day
>>>REMAIN RATE 4
```

**What i've tried?**
I've tried to change to simple UserRateThrottle, but nothing changed. So I think custom throttle is made correctly. Also I was changing between default Django cache/Redis server/Dummy cache and still not working as desired.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: write some unit tests?

Comment: So far i haven't written tests concerned throttling.

Comment: it's likely the best path forwards. Either that, or strip your question down so it only includes code relating to the throttling. nobody needs to know about instance.images.all().delete() to help you solve this. And if you strip it all down you'll almost certainly find the problem yourself, directly.